# How to do inner join a table with sub/derived query in JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql, spring-jdbc

How to do inner join a table with  sub/derived query in JPQL ?

Problem :

@Query("SELECT student FROM STUDENT student INNER JOIN (SELECT teacher FROM TEACHER teacher) st ON student.sCode=st.sCode")

How to achive above in JPQL?

Trying like this but not working:

@Query("SELECT student FROM STUDENT student" INNER JOIN (SELECT teacher FROM TEACHER teacher) st ON student.sCode=st.sCode)

Comment: I don't even see the point of the subquery.  What are you trying to achieve here, and why can't you just use a simple join?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is an example of a use case, so curious to know how to achive this

Comment: JPQL doesn't support the construct of joining to a subquery.  You would need to find some workaround.  Hence I ask you what the real requirement is, because the workaround for what you pasted above is just a simple join.

Answer (score 0):

From clause subqueries are supported since Hibernate 6.1. Also see the blog post that introduces this: https://in.relation.to/2022/06/24/hibernate-orm-61-features/